# Installing LyX 2.2.2 on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: software-installation, 16.10, lyx

I want to install [LyX 2.2.2](http://www.lyx.org/) on `Ubuntu 16.10`. I used the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyx-devel/release
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lyx
```

However, the above commands install `LyX 2.2.0`. Anyway to install [LyX 2.2.2](http://www.lyx.org/) on `Ubuntu 16.10`. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

At present, `sudo apt-get install lyx` actually installs the 2.2.2 version of lyx!

Comment: What installs lyx 2.2.2 ?

Comment: @George I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can either wait until they provide it through that repository (they still ship the old version), or compile it yourself.

In the second case, you can download it from [their website](http://www.lyx.org/Download#toc1) and follow the instructions inside to compile it (from the file INSTALL inside the package)

> ### Quick compilation guide
>
> These four steps will compile, test and install LyX:
>
> 0) Linux users beware: You need qt4 and qt4-devel packages
>        of the same version to compile LyX.
>
> In general, it is also recommended to have pkg-config
>        installed (the name might vary depending on your
>        distribution).
>
> 1) `./configure` configures LyX according to your system. You
>        may have to set `--with-qt-dir=<path-to-your-qt-installation>`
>        (for example, "`--with-qt-dir=/usr/share/qt4/`") if the
>        environment variable QTDIR is not set and pkg-config is not
>        available.
>
> ```
>  See Note below if `./configure` script is not present.
> ```
>
> 2) `make`
>        compiles the program.
>
> 3) `src/lyx`
>        runs the program so you can check it out.
>
> 4) `make install`
>        will install it. You can use "`make install-strip`" instead
>              if you want a smaller binary.

Answer (score 1):

The `ppa` that you referred doesn't currently host the latest version of `Lyx`.

---

You have currently two options:

1. Wait for the maintainer to upload the latest version of `Lyx` to the repository.
2. Compile it yourself.

---

If you choose the second option, then download the [tar.gz](ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/stable/2.2.x/lyx-2.2.2.tar.gz). Extract it and follow the instructions given in the`INSTALL` file inside `lyx-2.2.2`.

Except for the last step. In the last step, it instructs you to do `make install`. Instead do `checkinstall`. What this will do is create a `deb` package for you which you can easily install using `sudo dpkg -i` and uninstall using `apt`. This way is recommended because then when you decide to uninstall this package and install the one from the `ppa` when it gets available, you can easily remove it alongwith all its configuration files without any hassle. To install `checkinstall` do:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```